# Rails how to provide file download not through controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a list of file download links to files in my local folder
when I use this 
`<a href="/home/tmpfile.txt">download_link</a>`
It complains
No route matches [GET] "/home/tmpfile.txt"
and 
<%=link_to "download_link","/home/tmpfile.txt"%>
also get
No route matches [GET] "/home/tmpfile.txt"
add get "/home/tmpfile.txt" to config/route.rb does not solve the problem

I dont want to use the send_file function in controller because I have a lot of files
 
I am looking for something like this
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/mmdb/cdd/

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `/home/tmpfile.txt` the path in your filesystem or the path in the servers virtual filesystem?
If its the path in the filesystem you need to move it to the `public` folder  though its available in the webservers root directory!

Comment: I moved the file to public folder and it works now.Thank u! Is there any way to link to system paths rather than put file in public folder?

Comment: But does not rails have default folder tree view as the link I gave above?

Comment: public is the default root dir of the rails server for public files!

Comment: when I click the download_link, it opened the file in a new window rather than pop up a download dialogue. How to make it to save file rather than open it?

Comment: This is because a browser can interpret a .txt file. YOu have to use send_file when you want it pushed to the client as a download!

Comment: send_file requires an additional module with Apache FWIW.